# Invoke requests not for each iteration in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

For example I set number of threads(users) to 100,

I have 3 requests in ThreadGroup and I want every user to invoke request1 and request2, but only each third user to invoke request3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add If Controller with a check for every third thread number:

```
${__groovy(${__threadNum()} % 3 == 0)}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve, one of the options, most probably the easiest one, is putting your `request3` under [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) and configure the Throughput Controller to run it's children for 30% of virtual users:

[image]

More information: [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)